# MySql query join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've got the following tables in my Database:

**dishes**

```
id
name
```

**users**

```
id
email
```

**ingredients**

```
id
name
```

**dishes_ingredients** (this is used to represent the relation between dishes and ingredients)

```
id
dish_id
ingredient_id
```

**users_allergic_ingredients** (users are allergic to certain ingredients)

```
id
user_id
ingredient_id
```

Given a certain user (user_id), I need to get all the dishes to which the user is NOT allergic to.

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dishes
JOIN dishes_ingredients
ON dishes.id = dishes_ingredients.dish_id
WHERE dishes_ingredients.ingredient_id NOT IN
        (SELECT uai.ingredient_id FROM users_allergic_ingredients uai WHERE uai.user_id = 1)
```

But I get all the dishes and not only the dishes to which the customer is not allergic to.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting ingredients that are absent, not dishes.

I would approach this using aggregation:

```
SELECT di.dish_id
FROM dishes_ingredients di LEFT JOIN
     users_allergic_ingredients uai
     ON uai.ingredient_id = di.ingredient_id AND
        uai.user_id = 1
GROUP BY di.dish_id
HAVING COUNT(uai.integredient_id) = 0;
```

The `FROM` clause matches `uai` when the user is allergic to the ingredient.  The `HAVING` clause just determines that the count is zero.

Comment: What if I want to change the query and start from dishes instead of dishes_ingredients?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds wired, but you can use left join to users_allergic_ingredients and get only the rows the join to didn't succeed.
like this -

```
SELECT D.name
FROM dishes D
INNER JOIN dishes_ingredients DI
ON D.id = DI.dish_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_allergic_ingredients  UAI
ON UAI.user_id = @user_id 
and UAI.ingridient_id = DI.ingridient_id
WHERE UAI.ingridient_id IS NULL
```

notice the WHERE who deliberately asks the rows that were left out